# How to format values of the arrays of array as required?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, format

I have the following array which includes arrays of objects.

```
 const arr = [
  [
    {
      "key1": "keyName",
      "key2": "test name1"
    },
    {
      "key1": "keyDescription",
      "key2": "test description1"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "key1": "keyName",
      "key2": "test name2"
    },
    {
      "key1": "keyDescription",
      "key2": "test description2"
    }
  ]
]
```

The result which I required is as follows.

```
result = [
   {
    "key_name": "test name1",
    "key_description": "test description1"
   },
   {
    "key_name": "test name2",
    "key_description": "test description2"
   }
]
```

I have tried this using js 'map' and 'find' methods and it gived wrong format.

```
const res = arr.map(i => i.find(j => j.setting_code === "hotelRate")).map(k => k.setting_value)
```

I heard that this can be done using 'reduce'. I would be grateful for suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Please invest more time in proof-reading your question before you post it. Posting version A and then adding another requirement that adds quite a bunch of additional tasks after there are already answers is not the "nicest" way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution just uses `map` and then a `forEach` loop inside that map to add the `[key1]: key2` object pair to each object.

```js
const arr=[[{key1:"keyName",key2:"test name1"},{key1:"keyDescription",key2:"test description1"}],[{key1:"keyName",key2:"test name2"},{key1:"keyDescription",key2:"test description2"}]];

const result = arr.map(el => {
  const obj = {};
  el.forEach(({key1, key2}) => {
    const snakeKey = key1.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `_${letter.toLowerCase()}`);
    obj[snakeKey] = key2;
  })
  return obj;
})

console.log(result);
```

Edit: As Andreas points out in the comments, this *can* be written with a `reduce` method if that is a requirement:

```js
const result = arr.map(el => {
  return el.reduce((result, current) => {
    const snakeKey = current.key1.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `_${letter.toLowerCase()}`);
    result[snakeKey] = current.key2;
    return result;
  }, {});
})
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nick. The keys of the objects in the result array should be in the snake case. Can you modify your answer for that?

Comment: Sure, i have converted it

Comment: Oh, you changed the strings in the question. One moment...

Comment: @ruk91 That answer is also quite easy to transform so that it uses `.reduce()` (because you mentioned it in your question (_"I heard that this can be done using 'reduce'"_))

Comment: @Andreas, Can you provide an answer using reduce()...

Comment: Why do you need an answer using reduce specifically? It would basically do the same thing this answer does.

Comment: @ruk91 [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/6s0fa4rv/) but only as comment. Nick can add it to his answer (if he wants to).

Comment: @Nick, Yes, I just got that! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.map(function(item) {
  var props = {};
  
  item.forEach(function(keyValue) {
    props[keyValue["key1"]] = keyValue["key2"]; 
  });
  
  return props;
});
```